# Method doesn't perform once condition is met

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

this is my first time actually posting a question here, so I'm not too sure if this is how it works, but here it goes.

I'm modifying a particular code I've come across for a card game where the dealer deals a hand of five cards to four players. That part of the code is solid. The problem is after the cards are dealt, the dealer then rests the deck and turns over a single card. For some reason the turnover card either starts at the beginning (meaning it's the first card before the cards are actually dealt), or not at all, even if the condition is clearly met. I'm at my wits end and hoping for some guidance. I've frequent this forum many a times and has helped a great deal. Hopefully, you can help and assist me one more time. Thanks for your time and patience.

Here's the particular code in question.

```
protected void dealCards() {
    int startOffset = 0;
    SoundManager.getInstance(this).playSound(R.raw.shuffle1);

    //5 Cards for each player
    for (int i=0; i < AppData.NCards; i++) {            
        for (Hand hand : appData.getPlayInOrder()) {
            hand.addCard(appData.getDeck().popTopCard());

            //animation
            int[] handLocation = {0, 0};
            hand.getContainer().getLocationInWindow(handLocation);
            Log.e("COOR", "Hand: [" + handLocation[0] + "," + handLocation[1] + "]");
            int[] deckLocation = {0,0};
            deck.getLocationInWindow(deckLocation);
            Log.e("COOR", "Deck: [" + deckLocation[0] + "," + deckLocation[1] + "]");
            //move from deck location to hand location
            TranslateAnimation dealCardAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, deckLocation[0],
                                                                          Animation.ABSOLUTE, handLocation[0],
                                                                          Animation.ABSOLUTE, deckLocation[1],
                                                                          Animation.ABSOLUTE, handLocation[1]);
            dealCardAnimation.setDuration(400);
            dealCardAnimation.setStartOffset(600 * startOffset++);
            //end           
            hand.getCardsViews()[i].startAnimation(dealCardAnimation);
            redrawHand(hand);   
        }
    }
    if (startOffset == 5) {
        flipUpCard();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does redrawHand() and flipUpCard() do?

Comment: What is `AppData.NCards`? And what is `appData.getPlayInOrder()`? You increase `startOffset` by one in each iteration of the loop... do you definitely iterate exactly 5 times?

Comment: AppData.NCards is a variable in another class that equates to the amount of cards which equals 5. appData.getPlayInOrder() is a method in the AppData class that specifies the order in which the cards are dealt to the players. i.e to the dealer's left is p1, p2 and so forth.

Comment: Sorry, Volti, I didn't notice your reply. redrawHand()Updates the hand has cards are added. FlipUpCard is the method in question that's suppose to flip the last card over. For some reason it either does it as the first card, or not at all.

Comment: I decided to add a runnable in which to delay the flipUpCard method, so that it happens after the cards are dealt. I'm sure it's not a "real fix", but it works. I realized that the code in question actually does the calculations first before the cards are actually dealt.